# How does IMP work in iOS

Tags: objective-c

In order to understand `IMP`, I wrote some test codes and found a problem in the process of testing.

[image]

I got a surprise

[image]

[image]

Here is the code.

```
@interface Test : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end

@implementation Test

- (NSString *)description{
    return [[super description] stringByAppendingString:self.name];
}

- (void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"Test dealloc %@",self);
}

- (void)test:(NSString *)str{
    NSLog(@"- (void)test  %@",str);
}

+ (void)test:(NSString *)str{
    NSLog(@"+ (void)test  %@",str);
}

- (void)test{
    NSLog(@"- (void)test");
}

+ (void)test{
    NSLog(@"+ (void)test");
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    IMP imp = [[Test new] methodForSelector:@selector(test:)];
//    NSLog(@"%p",imp);
//    IMP imp1 = [Test instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(test)];
    IMP imp2 = [Test methodForSelector:@selector(test:)];
//    NSLog(@"%p",imp2);
    imp2();
    NSLog(@"%p",imp2);
//    imp2 = [Test methodForSelector:@selector(test)];
//    imp2();
//    imp();
//    imp = [[Test new] methodForSelector:@selector(test:)];
//    NSLog(@"%p",imp);
//    imp();
//    imp1();
//    imp1();
//    imp2();
//    imp2();
//    void (*func)(id,SEL,NSString *) = (void *)imp;
//    func([Test class],@selector(test:),@"");
//    void (*func1)(id,SEL,NSString *) = (void *)imp1;
//    func1([Test class],@selector(test:),@"ha");
//    void (*func2)(id,SEL,NSString *) = (void *)imp2;
//    func2([Test class],@selector(test:),@"haha");
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

There's no problem when I run a single `IMP`.But when I run more than one `IMP` will crash for `BAC_ACCESS` and it only happens with the function which has arguments.So，why it can work with one and crash with two.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.  It is very hard to read and we have to retype the entire thing in order to experiment.  Post the text instead.  I realize you're showing screenshots of the IDE\ debugger, but we really need the text.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour; your program may crash, or may just continue to run in an invalid state. You need to pass the correct arguments to the function calls (receiver + selector + method args).

Comment: This is conceptually a dupe of this question/answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305191/what-was-the-second-parameter-in-id-impid-sel-used-for

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have a crash, because you need path `id`, `SEL` and also `NSString *` where needed.
Better cast to actual function prototype to have compiler errors when you call it wrong, instead of using direct IMP variables.
Apple should forbid `()` operator for `IMP`s and declare is as `void *` instead.
But people rarely use `IMP` for direct method calls, so there is no complains.

Comment: I know this usage is not correct,i want to know why this `IMP` can work once and crash with the second usage.I think it's should be work always or crash always.

Comment: @xuanpf, all is get wrong after first call already, but CPU doesn't know about it eat. You will get crash some where in other place any way and will not understand why. You get undefined behaviour as Hamish said before, because IMP doesn't know actual function prototype and handle objects in call stack wrong.